# Regression for Deskew Document problem

Tags: deep-learning, keras, loss-function, image

I am currently at an impasse regarding my regression problem.

My goal is to generate a model that rotates correctly an image. My images are documents (invoices for example). Each document is either in `grayscale` or `binarized`.

Initially, I have around 150 images deskewed.

I generate, with rotate function around `5000 images` rotated. For each image, I generate 36 new images with an angle different (normalized between 0 and 1).

```
def rotate_with_white_background(img, angle):
    # converted to have an alpha layer
    im2 = img.convert('RGBA')
    # rotated image
    rot = im2.rotate(angle, expand=True, resample=Image.BICUBIC)
    # a white image same size as rotated image
    fff = Image.new('RGBA', rot.size, (255,)*4)
    # create a composite image using the alpha layer of rot as a mask
    out = Image.composite(rot, fff, rot)
    # save your work (converting back to mode='1' or whatever..)
    return out.convert(img.mode)



list_angle = list(range(0,360,10))
for img in list_img:
    for angle in list_angle:
        full_name_img_in = os.path.join(pathin, img)
        image = Image.open(full_name_img_in)
        image_skew = rotate_with_white_background(image, angle)
        full_name_img_out = os.path.join(pathout_no_resize, os.path.splitext(img)[0] + str(angle) + "t.png")
        image_skew.save(full_name_img_out)
```

My data is stocked on folders. In the `train` folder, I have as many sub-folders as angle generated. So to load my data, I use `regression_flow_from_directory`.

```
def regression_flow_from_directory_one_output(flow_from_directory_gen, list_of_values):
    for x, y in flow_from_directory_gen:
        y = list(map(lambda x: int(x), y))
        yield x, list_of_values[y]                  


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)
resize = (244,244)
batch_size = 8

# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(path_train_commun, class_mode="sparse", batch_size=batch_size, target_size=resize, color_mode="grayscale")
# load and iterate test dataset
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(path_test_commun, class_mode="sparse", batch_size=batch_size, target_size=resize, color_mode="grayscale")


train_it_generator_img_with_label_one = regression_flow_from_directory_one_output(train_it, list_of_values_tuple)
test_it_generator_img_with_label_one  = regression_flow_from_directory_one_output(test_it, list_of_values_tuple)
```

Then, I use `resnet_v1` to create my model.

This is my code:

```
def resnet_v1(input_shape, depth, num_classes=10):
    if (depth - 2) % 6 != 0:
        raise ValueError('depth should be 6n+2 (eg 20, 32, 44 in [a])')
    # Start model definition.
    num_filters = 16
    num_res_blocks = int((depth - 2) / 6)

    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = resnet_layer(inputs=inputs)
    # Instantiate the stack of residual units
    for stack in range(3):
        for res_block in range(num_res_blocks):
            strides = 1
            if stack > 0 and res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stack
                strides = 2  # downsample
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=x,
                             num_filters=num_filters,
                             strides=strides)
            y = resnet_layer(inputs=y,
                             num_filters=num_filters,
                             activation=None)
            if stack > 0 and res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stack
                # linear projection residual shortcut connection to match
                # changed dims
                x = resnet_layer(inputs=x,
                                 num_filters=num_filters,
                                 kernel_size=1,
                                 strides=strides,
                                 activation=None,
                                 batch_normalization=False)
            x = keras.layers.add([x, y])
            x = Activation('relu')(x)
        num_filters *= 2

    # Add classifier on top.
    # v1 does not use BN after last shortcut connection-ReLU
    x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=8)(x)
    y = Flatten()(x)

    z1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(y)

    z3 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(z1)


    outputs_angle_value = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output_angle_value')(z3)   

    # Instantiate model.
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs_angle_value)
    return model



input_shape = (244,244,1)
depth = 8
from keras_radam import RAdam

opt = RAdam(total_steps=5000, warmup_proportion=0.1, min_lr=1e-5)

model_one_output = resnet_v1(input_shape, depth)
model_one_output.compile(loss= angle_error_regression, optimizer=opt)


history = model_one_output.fit_generator(
    train_it_generator_img_with_label_one,
    steps_per_epoch= nb_data_in_train / 8,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data= test_it_generator_img_with_label_one,
    validation_steps= nb_data_test / 8,
    callbacks=[tensorboard, early_stop, checkpoint],
    verbose=1
)
```

Throughout the `epochs` loss decreases but when I predict the results are very bad.

I tried to increase the number of `epochs`, change the loss and activation, generate more data.

If someone has an idea, I would be grateful. :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Data Science SE! Please edit your question to describe what you depict as "very bad" results. Also, I'm not sure to understand, from the text, how you are training the model.

Comment: Hi!  I'm going to detail on how I generate the data. And I'll attach some predictions results